# What do fibers/future actually do?

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, node-fibers

What does the line of code below do?

```
Npm.require('fibers/future');
```

I looked online for examples and I came across a few like this:

```
Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
var accessToken = new Future();
```

What will `accessToken` variable be in this case?

Comment: It's all about callbacks and Promises. It allows you to run async code synchronously.

Answer (score 12):

Question is a bit old but my 2 cents:

As Molda said in the comment, Future's main purpose is to make async things work synchronously.
`future` instance comes with 3 methods:

- `future.wait()` basically tells your thread to basically pause until told to resume.
- `future.return(value)`, first way to tell waiting `future` he can resume, it's also very useful since it returns a value wait can then be assigned with, hence lines like `const ret = future.wait()` where ret becomes your returned value once resumed.
- `future.throw(error)`, quite explicit too, makes your blocking line throw with given error.

Making things synchronous in javascript might sound a bit disturbing but it is sometimes useful. In `Meteor`, it's quite useful when you are chaining async calls in a `Meteor.method` and you want its result to be returned to the client. You could also use `Promises` which are now fully supported by `Meteor` too, I've used both and it works, it's up to your liking.

A quick example:

```
Meteor.methods({
  foo: function() {
    const future = new Future();
    someAsyncCall(foo, function bar(error, result) {
      if (error) future.throw(error);
      future.return(result);
    });
    // Execution is paused until callback arrives
    const ret = future.wait(); // Wait on future not Future
    return ret;
  }
});
```

Comment: I have had problems with 'throw', seeing a message "Future resolved more than once". I think that with future.throw although callbacks are resolved it does not halt execution. See here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fibers. A structure like "if (error) future.throw(error) else future.return(result)" should be safer.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think future.return also does not halt exceution.

Comment: You need to make sure that your future only throws and returns once. The best was to do this is to always `return future.throw()` as the throw()/ return() itself does not end the execution.